# matrix summation.

Tags: matrices

Hi have problem understanding how the summation is computed within the second enclosure on the right end side. I am not able to see how the summation work when the squared error term(e) is put into it.

$$
\hat{V}(b) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i'\right)^{-1}\left ( \sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2x_ix_i' \right ) \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i' \right)^{-1}
$$

As you all ready know 
$$
X'X = \sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i'
$$
As I am struggling quite a bit with matrices, and as you can see on a very basic level I hope someone would be able to help me with an detailed explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Try considering the diagonal matrix $E=\mathrm{diag}(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ and the expression $X'E^2X$.

Comment: Im sorry but I am not able to understand what is going on.